# What to do in case of an item stolen from your luggage?

Tags: lost-luggage

I traveled recently and, already on my final destination, I noticed my camera missed from my cargo hold luggage.

I called the airline company and they told me to complain to the handling company.

The handling company says they only accept complaints on arrival.

Meanwhile I filled a complain in the airline company but they take up to 28 days to answer.

**What can one effectively do in such situation?**

Comment: Inform the local police.

Comment: Check your condition of carriage. Many airlines prohibit the placement of valuables in checked luggage.

Comment: Determine if you have any insurance coverage and file a claim through them, i.e. traveller's insurance (potentially through your employer, if it is a business trip), credit card benefits, homeowner's or renters...

Answer (score 2):

The common rule is to never put anything valuable in your luggage. No cameras, no electronics, etc.

The maximum you are typically insured for by the airline is defined in an decades old international agreement as $ 20 / pound. That barely covers simple clothing; but obviously airlines have little interest in increasing that, and understandably so, as it is very easy to make false claims. Your airline *might* have a higher amount, but don't hold your breath.

If you paid with your credit card, you might have additional insurance, and that might well cover it - depending on the credit card, limits are nothing, some thousand dollar, or even a lot more (for those high-end cards that cost $500 / year).
However, electronis, cameras, etc. are often excluded explicitly.

So 1. file a claim with the airline; 2. contact your credit card company about the remainder (after the airline paid something or nothing). 3. Learn from it: *Nothing valuable in the lugagge*.

Comment: I don't think that your common rule is correct.  I would state it as `Never put anything in checked luggage that you care about seeing again`.  The monetary value of the object doesn't matter.  That said, high priced objects are more fo a target.  However I once had someone crack open a locked Pelican case and made off with a $200 digital camera instead of the $2000 film SLR and ginormous lens.

Comment: Well, I understand the rule and I usually use it. My hand luggage was forced to go to the cargo hold due to lack of space in the cabin. With the pressure of boarding etc. I had only time to remove my wallet (that I just had put there to pass security).